# R - Find rows based on group factors

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out a way to find specific values based on each factor within R. In other words, how can I keep all rows that suffice a certain condition for each factor, even if that specific row fails a condition but it's same factor passes the condition on another row?

So I have something like this:

```
   gender values  fruit
1       M     20  apple
2       M     22   pear
3       F     24  mango
4       F     19  mango
5       F      9  mango
6       F     17  apple
7       M     18 banana
8       M     22 banana
9       M     12 banana
10      M     14  mango
11      F      7  apple
12      F      8  apple
```

I want every fruit and has at least one F gender (even if that fruit has some M's). It's also possible to have multiple genders, such as neutral (not shown). So my ideal output out be this:

```
   gender values  fruit
1       M     20  apple
3       F     24  mango
4       F     19  mango
5       F      9  mango
6       F     17  apple
10      M     14  mango
11      F      7  apple
12      F      8  apple
```

Notice that the banana and pear are missing, that's because those fruits ONLY have M's and no F's. Also, rows 1 and 10 are still there even though those are M's, because there are other apples and mangos that have F's, it still applies. Please let me know if this is possible. Thank you!

Below is my code for replicating this data:

```
gender <- c("M","M","F","F","F","F","M","M","M","M","F","F")
values <- c(20,22,24,19,9,17,18,22,12,14,7,8)
fruit <- c("apple","pear","mango","mango","mango","apple","banana","banana","banana","mango","apple","apple")
df <- data.frame(gender, values, fruit)
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
df[duplicated(df[,c("fruit","gender")]),]
ave(df$gender, df$fruit, FUN=function(x) ifelse(x=='F','yes','no'))
```

Also, third party libraries are welcomed but I prefer to stay within R (packages stats and plyr are fine as I have those on my system).

Comment: No... It's not homework and if you have the link, please supply it. If it turns out to be the same, I'll delete this..

Comment: The sentence "I want every fruit and has _only_ F genders" (my emphasis) is unfortunately somewhat unclear. From your desired output, it seems like you want each fruit which have _any_ (i.e. at least one) row where `gender == "F"`.

Comment: Yes, sorry. You're correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df[df$fruit %in% unique(df[df$gender =='F', ]$fruit),]
#   gender values fruit
#1       M     20 apple
#3       F     24 mango
#4       F     19 mango
#5       F      9 mango
#6       F     17 apple
#10      M     14 mango
#11      F      7 apple
#12      F      8 apple
```

Comment: I like it. Should be very efficient.

Comment: Thank you! This works and was very helpful in showing me other functions that I didn't know about in R.

Comment: You're welcome. Run each part of the code separately for clarity :)

Answer (score 3):

Possible `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(any(gender == "F")) .SD, by = fruit]
#    fruit gender values
# 1: apple      M     20
# 2: apple      F     17
# 3: apple      F      7
# 4: apple      F      8
# 5: mango      F     24
# 6: mango      F     19
# 7: mango      F      9
# 8: mango      M     14
```

I like the other approach, so here's a `data.table` equivalent using binary join

```
setkey(setDT(df), fruit)[.(unique(df[gender == "F", fruit], by = "fruit"))]
#    gender values fruit
# 1:      F     17 apple
# 2:      F      7 apple
# 3:      F      8 apple
# 4:      M     20 apple
# 5:      F     24 mango
# 6:      F     19 mango
# 7:      F      9 mango
# 8:      M     14 mango
```

Comment: Thank you. `data.table` approaches are always great for their speed and flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

The base r, the `data.table` and here I provide the `dplyr` solution even though some outputs are different (at least in order of the results).

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(fruit) %>% filter(any(gender == "F"))
Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
Groups: fruit

  gender values fruit
1      M     20 apple
2      F     24 mango
3      F     19 mango
4      F      9 mango
5      F     17 apple
6      M     14 mango
7      F      7 apple
8      F      8 apple
```

Comment: Thanks for the dplyr comparison. Very useful for future viewers.